# PowerShell: How do you delete a folder with a name that starts with a dot (e.g. ".svn")

Tags: powershell

Tried this:

```
Remove-Item "C:\foo\.svn"
```

but this is the error that I encountered

```
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\foo\.svn' because it does no
t exist.
At line:1 char:12
+ Remove-Item <<<<  "C:\foo\.svn"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\foo\.svn:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Comment: Remove-Item "C:\foo\.svn" works just fine.  Are you sure the directory exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure one of the gurus has a cleaner way, but this should work:

```
gci | where {$_.name -match '.svn'} | remove-item
```

Answer (score 9):

Hmm, this works for me.  Are you sure the directory exists?  Perhaps it is hidden.  If so try:

```
Remove-Item C:\foo\.svn -force -recurse
```

Comment: Yes, subversion directories are hidden by default.

Comment: In that case, the -force is required IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Remove-Item C:\foo\.svn
```

or this:

```
Remove-Item C:\foo\\.svn
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 rm .test
```

worked for me, no problems here.

Comment: I tried that also to make sure, are you sure the path is right?

Comment: This is my actual code: `Remove-Item "$location\$directory`.  However if I piped the Remove-Item with the result of Get-ChildItem it works.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to that permissons are not right, one thing to try is to add the -Force flag:

```
Remove-Item "C:\foo\.svn" -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file actually exists and doesn't have a extension you're not providing. Try listing the contents of the directory to it isn't the directory not found and that it actually contains the files you think it does.